Need to avoid recursive inheritance
Hi I have a parent class called DedicatedToServers with a child class called Blog. Blog has 3 children, User, Post, Category, Comment
In my code If I do this
package Blog;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
use Moose;
extends 'DedicatedToServers';

my $dbh = DedicatedToServers->DbConnect();

All is good, however if i then create an object of User like this
package User;
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
use Moose;
extends 'Blog';

I get a recursive inheritance error
So how do I avoid that, do I have to extend the base class each time, or is there away to extend a class that is extended from another class

Why would User, Post, Category, Comment extend Blog?! I’d expect a Blog to have Posts, Posts to have Comments, etc.

It feels like you should be using composition rather than inheritance for the relationship between Blog and User, Post, Category and Comment.

I get a recursive inheritance error The code you have shown does not produce that.

Firstly, I would make DedicatedToServers a Moose::Role:
package DedicatedToServers;

use Moose::Role;

sub DbConnect { ... }

1;

Then, blog can be a standalone thing with the role DedicatedToServers and it's old "children" can now just have an instance of a blog:
package Blog;

use Moose;

with 'DedicatedToServers';

has dbh => (
  is => 'ro',
  default => sub {
    return $_[0]->DbConnect();
  }
);

...

1;

Do this for all 3 "children":
package User;

use Moose;

has blog => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => 'Blog',
  required => 1
);

...

1;

Now instantiate with dependency injection ie:
my $blog = Blog->new();
my $user = User->new(blog => $blog);

Now you can access the blog information through an attribute ie: $self->blog, and avoid tangled inheritance.

Thanks for the response, I'm going to try this. If DedicatedToServer is a Role, does it still need a constructor defined?

@user3183111, its a "Mixin" meaning its methods, and attributes now become available on the class that calls with, but without using inheritance. Moose creates constructors for you, you shouldn't be writing them yourself unless you really want to change some things, and know what you're doing.

Sounds similar to a 'friend class' in C++

@user3183111 Sort of. It's not really about state though when compared to friend class, it's more about appending to a class without inheriting, or using composition. I like to think of mixins/roles as the OO version of union types.
